# Is it possible to create a openGL VBO/Display List in a non-main thread

Tags: java, multithreading, opengl, lwjgl

I have a infinitely generating world that works pretty much fine.  Every time a new chunk is generated it's height map is generated in a second thread.  But creating the display list is impossible to do because there is "no GLContext" in any thread but the main one.  This means that every time a new chunk is generated there is a small lag spike which when a few are generated at once becomes noticeable.

What I'm asking is whether or not there is a way to create the display list or vertex buffer object in another thread and then bind it or something in the main one?

I have already tried it with VBO's but it was very slow compared to display lists.

Comment: Yes, you need to use multiple render contexts to do this, because only one thread can take ownership of a context at any given moment. Furthermore, you need to enable resource sharing between the multiple contexts. But once you do this, certain types of objects (such as Buffer Objects and display lists as well) can be shared between contexts. Note that each context has its own unique state machine, the only thing you really share is the data and buffer / display list names.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A possibly simpler approach would be to use the second thread to generate the VBO data in memory and then use asynchronous data transfer to the GPU (using the now ubiquitous [GL_ARB_pixel_buffer_object](http://www.seas.upenn.edu/~pcozzi/OpenGLInsights/OpenGLInsights-AsynchronousBufferTransfers.pdf)) from the main thread.

Rendering data from a VBO should be fairly fast nowadays. Do make use of `glDrawElements`, `glMultiDrawElements`, `glPrimitiveRestartIndex` and the rest of the family in order to minimize the number of draw calls. Display lists then should not be needed at all.

Comment: Man, I can't begin to thank you enough for all the answers you provided me, I feel like I can really work on my project now.  A huge thank you :-D